# Filter AWS api results by the lack of a field

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, boto3

I am using Boto3 for a project, one part of which involves looking up unallocated elastic ip addresses. The filter API is usually very expressive, but I can't figure out how to use it for this use case, which doesn't seem all that unusual.

How can I query for an EIP without any associations?

For example, the following doesn't work:

```
boto3.resource("ec2").vpc_addresses.filter(Filters=[{"Name": "association-id", "Values": []}])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[addr['PublicIp'] for addr in boto3.client("ec2").describe_addresses()['Addresses'] if 'AssociationId' not in addr]
```

1. Get all addresses
2. Find the addresses with no association
3. Print the PublicIp

Comment: I guess I could've been more explicit -- it's straightforward to do this in memory, as you've pointed out. I was more curious  whether the filter api supports these kinds of operations.

Comment: Well. you need some results to filter it. There is no such thing called `vpc_addresses` in ec2 resource

Comment: Thanks, but you're probably looking at an old version. https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.vpc_addresses